# Rendering required and error classes with Django Form Fields, in a custom template

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to render the required and error attributes as part of the markup spit by the field in the template. I know that this can be done by using form.as_p, etc. when the layout is auto generated.

I however have a complex 2 column layout for the form. Is it possible to include **required_css_class = 'required'** which is part of the form class while spitting out html for individual fields?

I need to do this because I want to drive jquery validation from the generated html without a lot of extra work.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `required_css_class` appears to be in use by `forms.BoundField.css_classes` and  `forms.BaseForm._html_output` which is only for `as_p`, `as_table`, and such.

It's not a part of the regular widget rendering.

You could use that same `css_classes` method to return the classes for your element though, so  I think the easiest solution would be to wrap the `<input>` with an element and give *that* the class `{{ field.css_classes }}`, and modify your validation selector.

---

Alternatively, here's a way to hack an error class into the errored fields:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.errors:
            if not field == '__all__': 
                # errors dict can have key __all__ for non field errors.
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = \
                    self.fields[field].widget.attrs.get('class', '') + 'error'
```

To use `required_css_class`, you'd have to use the `BoundField.css_classes` method, which would involve hacking into the base form `__getitem__` and `__iter__` since BoundField is constructed on demand. The above method is easier.

Comment: what is `form` referring to in the above sample?